# PHP SimpleXML has Child

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

How can check if `$xml` has child "students"?

I'm using SimpleXML to use Xml in php:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('log.xml');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is marked as a dupe, but the chosen answer to the linked question is wrong.  The answer selected below is correct, and is identical to the highest voted answer on the linked question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) call for that

```
$node = new SimpleXMLElement('<foo><students>test</students></foo>');

var_dump(isset($node->students));
```

> bool(true)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Solved my problem, all accept the answer asap.

Answer (score 1):

```
if( isset($xml->students) )
   // Do
```